# Capture image with out saving on Device using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi is it possible to capture an Image with out saving to ios device .This is  a question that is worrying me.

Can any please give me an idea how to achieve it.

Comment: Your question is too general. At least could you describe what are you doing (how do you capture images)?

Comment: When you take a photo with `UIImagePickerController`, nothing is saved unless you write specific code to save the image somewhere. What is your concern?

Comment: my english is bad at some times , sorry for that @Vitaly.S

Comment: Thank you !! Im pretty naive to Uiimagepickercontroller. Thank you i have figured it out.

Comment: It is definetly possible. Even more: you have to specifically save it if you want to, well, save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
- (void)takePhoto
{
    UIImagePickerController * pc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pc.delegate = self;

    pc.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    pc.allowsEditing = YES;

    [self presentViewController:pc animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController Delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        UIImage * image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }];
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to save the image you can simply save it to the Caches directory (see the apple docs for [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for info on how to do this, or other stack overflow questions. This is preferred to NSUserDefaults although that would work too.

If you want to simply send it (via email, share, or API upload) you dont have to save it first. You can use the in-memory version that resides in the self.imageView.image property above.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help. here is a small question folowwing it up. I want to sent the capture image. Is it good practise to save in nsuser deafaults or as nsdata and send it. Once the confirmation is  received i will set that nsuser defaults or nsdata to null